# Location tracking in react native even if app is closed?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, location

I am looking for Location tracking in react native even if app is closed?

I have tried react-native-location but how i will track location and get response from gps when
even app is closed. I am looking for google timeline functionality, location is even track when app is closed.

Comment: You're pretty much going to have to drop into native code to do this.  On Android you'd need to run it in a Foreground Service, and react native doesn't do services at all. YOu can do the UI in react native and the location logic in native most likely.  But even with that, you will still be at risk of being killed for resources over time or if the user runs a resource heavy app-  foreground activities take priority.  Also, if the user kills your app then you won't get updates, you can at most get them when backgrounded, not when actually closed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this library, but it's not free for Android.

https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation

Answer (score 2):

For such a requirement accomplishment, you should have to create a background task and also need to create a service in android to run up location tracking in the background state and even in the app's kill state.

For this, we can use the below libraries, with the combination of these two libraries the requirement can be implemented.

1. https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch
2. https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service

React native background fetch is to start the run of a specified task even if the app is in its kill state, and geolocation service to keep track of user location data.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where i need to contact an API after a certain time even if app is closed, So I used [react-native-background-actions](https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions) to fetch the API in a loop,you can do the similar

```
const trackLocation = async () => {
  await new Promise(async () => {
    for (let i = 1; BackgroundService.isRunning(); i++) {
      try {
        // depends on which lib you are using
        await getLocation();
      } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
      }
      await sleep(20000);
    }
  });
};
```

example - https://github.com/Rapsssito/react-native-background-actions#example-code